# Exporting satellite image raster causes change in pixels using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcgis-pro, export

I have a WorldView-2 satellite raster which I re-project from WGS84 to WGS84/UTM using Raster Project. I wish to export this from outside the geodatabase so I can share it with colleagues. However, when exporting the re-projected raster to my desktop (via right-clicking on it from the contents pane -> export), the exported raster has a changed pixel value range and white stripes appear where there was previously no data. I used the default settings when exporting.

The white background is caused by areas beyond the original raster extent (i.e., areas of no-data in the original raster) being assigned high-pixel values (65535) when exported. To resolve this, I've tried to set the "NoData Value" to zero. This removes the white background stripes. However, it also causes the exported raster's pixel range to begin from 1 rather than 0.

How can I export my raster image without creating pixels beyond the original extents or changing the pixel value range?